# High stability external crystal for PIC?

Tags: pic, crystal

I have a question regarding the external crystal for the PIC
In what application the designer of a circuit should consider a high stability crystal TCXO for the PIC ?
I have seen some PIC have just an expensive regular crystal and some other have a TCXO which cost more.
My appreciation to the answers

Comment: The TCXO's cost more but are more stable. This question is based mostly on opinions and could be answered by comparing datasheets and pricing between the two. It may be best to restrict questions that are specific or design based questions.  Please see: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Many will use a cheap resonator or these days more commonly an internal RC oscillator for most applications.  Timing accuracy is critical if drift accumulates or timing has to track a separate (hopefully accurate) clock at tight timing requirements.  Often timing is over specified and the RC can be made to work in a surprising number of cases by comparing it to the other device and adjusting to accommodate.

Answer (score 1):

Use the TCXO if you need more temperature stability than a simple crystal will provide.

Comment: Quite, it does not ostensibly improve any other characteristic (though you should find the the TCXO will use best of breed crystals) but may incorporate supply noise and variation mitigation and all sorts of other things that will give additional benefits.  Numerous DIY TCXO projects have been published in the HAM radio (and other) literature in the past.